# Theming D7 Nice Menus Subchildren by Taxonomy Term

Tags: menu, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have been pondering on how to modify the default output of Nice Menus' list elements and make each `<li>` group a list of nodes by taxonomy term. This is the default output of a sub-menu:

```
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Parent
    <ul>
      <li>Sub 1</li>
      <li>Sub 2</li>
      <li>Sub 3</li>
      <li>Sub 4</li>
      <li>Sub 5</li>
      <li>Sub 6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
</ul>
```

My goal is to group sub-children based on a taxonomy term such as:

```
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Parent
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>Term 1</h3>
        <a href="#">Sub 1</a>
        <a href="#">Sub 2</a>
        <a href="#">Sub 3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Term 2</h3>
        <a href="#">Sub 4</a>
        <a href="#">Sub 5</a>
        <a href="#">Sub 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
</ul>
```

How can I customize this on template.php?

Answer (score 0):

there's some nice hook code in [here](http://codegurus.eu/2011/10/replace-menu-links-in-drupal-7-using-menu_link-menu_tree-hooks/) which allow you to alter menu links and menu tree